# Correct classification of passenger

Tags: python

I'm writing a code that asks the user to enter the number of miles flying and places the passenger into the correct classification. It tells me "NameError: name 'passenegerClass' is not defined" when i try to run the program. I"m still new to coding and am pretty lost, anyone know what I"m missing.

```
def getTheNumberOfMiles():
    miles = float(input("What is the number of miles you are flying?"))
    return miles

def classifyPassenger(miles):
    if miles<10000:
        return 'Z'
    elif miles>=10000 and miles<50000:
        return'C'
    elif miles>=50000 and miles<100000:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'A'

def outputPassengerClass(passengerClass):
    print ("This passenger beloings to class: " + passengerClass)

def main():

    miles = getTheNumberOfMiles()
    passengerClass = classifyPassenger(miles)
    outputPassengerClass(passenegerClass)


main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple typo on the second-to-last line, as the error says:

```
outputPassengerClass(passenegerClass)
```

Should be:

```
outputPassengerClass(passengerClass)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main method has a typo. passenegerClass is not the same thing as passengerClass. Usually when python says that a name is not defined, and you are sure that you initialized the variable, it's because you have a typo in your code